# Is there a way to create symlink[s] to directory's *contents*?

Tags: bash, directory, symlink

I have the core code, which is the same for all projects, except one configuration file.
I can't symlink to that dir because, this assumes that the config file will be also symlinked.

Is there a way in Linux/Bash to do that? 
I thought to write a script which creates a usual directory, then symlinks all the contents (=files and dirs) from the core, and then, I can just create there the config file.

Not sure if that's the best solution however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mkdir someothersite && cd someothersite 
find /your/project -type f ! -name 'CONFIGFILE' -exec ln -s \{\} ./ \;
```

*Note* this works well if there are no subdirectories in `/your/project` directory. If there are subdirectories it's much more complicated.

By the way, I'd use a VS for this. E.g. central repo, checkout, setup config...

HTH

Answer (score 1):

@Zsolt, thanks, with the help of your answer I could answer my own question.

```
find /your/project -maxdepth 1 ! -name "CONFIGFILE" -exec ln -s \{\} ./ \;
```

-maxdepth 1 makes sure the find command doesn't go recursive. Thus, symlinks can be created for the directories *and* for the files. In other words, for the *directory contents* Exactly what I needed. :)